# JQuery UI drag element inside li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to drag an element that is inside a li but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

      $('dragme').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid',
        cursor: 'move',
        appendTo: 'body'
      });

      $('#drop').droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          newItem = ui.draggable.clone();

          newItem.removeClass('ui-draggable');
          newItem.removeClass('ui-draggable-handle');

          newItemId = newItem.attr('id')+'_clone';


          newItem.attr('id',newItemId);
          newItem.attr('name',newItemId);

          if (!newItem.hasClass('cloned')) {
            $('#drop').append(newItem);  
          }

      newItem.addClass('cloned');
      newItem.draggable({
        containment: "parent",
        helper: "original"
      });

    }
  });

});
```

and here is the html code:

```
    <p>Drag them</p>
    <div id="drag" style="border: solid 1px red; height: 200px; width: 500px">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div id="item1" class="dragme" style="background-color: #e74c3c; color: #fff; height: 50px; width: 50px">
            <p>Item 1</p>
          </div>          
        </li>
        <li>
          <div id="item2" class="dragme" style="background-color: #2980b9;color: #fff;  height: 50px; width: 50px">
            <p>Item 2</p>
          </div>
        </li>        
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drop" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 200px; width: 500px">
</div>
```

The problem is that the element inside the li "can't" be grabbed and then dragged to the drop zone. If I take the divs out of the li, the code works perfectly. Has anyone faced something like this?

I just don't wanna drag the whole li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$('dragme')` to `$('.dragme')`

(I haven't actually tested this as a solution, it might not actually be the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pointer-events: none;` CSS class to prevent the divs from grabbing the mouse events.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for the help! Your suggestion also worked. :-)